# Initialization of 1D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have this simple code and I need to initialize the `Range[]` array, but I get this error:

> ```
> >gcc c.cpp c.cpp: In function 'int main()': c.cpp:16:7: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token 
> Range[]={12,22,35,45,69,74,79,78,66};
> ```

How can solve it please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
    
using namespace std;
using std::string;
    
int Range[8]; 
    
int main(){
       
    Range[]={12,22,35,45,69,74,79,78,66};
    
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
       cout<< Range[i] <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're compiling C++, you should use `g++`, not `gcc`. The latter is a C compiler.

Comment: You can't separate the declaration and assignment of a C-style array like this. In C++, you can with [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), though. BTW, your array holds only 8 values, but you are trying to assign 9 values.

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is actually *assignment* and not initialization.

And you can't assign to an array, just copy to it.

The solution? Do actual initialization:

```
int Range[]={12,22,35,45,69,74,79,78,66};
```

Note that since I didn't specify a size for the array, the compiler will automatically set the size to *nine* elements, as in the initializer list. Unlike your current definition of the array where you set the size to only eight elements.

I also recommend you make the variable a *local* variable inside the `main` function. Global variables are to be avoided.